# Multiple queues with same routing key from an exchange with Apache Camel

Tags: java, rabbitmq, apache-camel, rabbitmq-exchange

I am trying to bind two queues to an exchange. Both queues must consume the same message (routing key). I am able to create these two queues directly with RabbitMQ.
However, when I try the same with Apache Camel, it throws an exception stating "Multiple consumers are not allowed for the same endpoint". I am assuming that this must be possible with Camel since it is a basic feature in RabbitMQ.

I am using [Camel RabbitMQ](http://camel.apache.org/rabbitmq.html) plugin. Is there some additional configuration that's required to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Since Apache Camel is a generic integration framework based on Enterprise integration patterns   , it does not allows multiple listeners on the same route. So while RabbitMQ supports multiple queues bonded to an exchange , Camel will not carry forward such bindings . What you can try to do however is this.

1. Have two separate exchanges with each exchange bonded to a single queue.
2. This will allow you to have two separate consumers each bonded to a single respective exchange
3. Do an exchange to exchange direct binding between the two exchanges created in the previous step.

This should help.